# GTM Preview mode keeps returning "Out of Memory" error

Tags: google-tag-manager

Recently, I started to experience "out of memory" error while previewing in GTM and it is getting more frequent now.

I am certain whenever I try submitting a form in a [preview mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RsWA.png), this error would definitely occur while others are pretty random.

Have anyone experienced the same thing, started 2 weeks ago? Any idea how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Roman

Answer (score 0):

Try tracing the variables and overall code that fires on the form submission. Looks like something in the container causes rapid memory leak.

There are a few approaches to debugging. I would just read the code and see if certain parts of it are poorly structured. If I can't see anything immediately, which is pretty unlikely, I would start inserting breakpoints in devtools to get closer to the bug.

A simpler, but longer approach would be disabling parts of logic in GTM and reproducing the out of memory error to find the exact trigger/variable/tag/template that causes the issue. After that just debug the code in question.

Comment: Thanks BNazaruk, I'll give it a try. BTW, It seems to happen for all forms (constructed with 3 differents platforms i.e. custom built, iapply and sitecore) which puzzling me.

Comment: That may indicate something in your browser, likely a plugin conflict. Try a different browser or incognito.

Comment: I've tried MS Edge as well as incognito mode. Both returned the same result, unfortunately. I'll try Vivaldi and Firefox

Comment: Nah, no reason to try further. probably something in your GTM. Likely a variable that has an infinite loop and is being used in all the form triggers or something similar to that. Back to normal debugging :)

Comment: Finally, I managed to unearth 1 of the root causes that responsible for 95% of the problem, after going through a hassle to pause/unpause all tags within my GTM account.  Apparently, a facebook pixel was the culprit for the whole drama.  Adding an exception in the trigger to evaluate {{debug mode}} == true, somehow solve the problem. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help @BNazaruk

Comment: very weird that a facebook pixel would do something like that. It's probably nasty enough  to declare global variables with its minified JS, so you could try putting its code in a closure to see if that helps things. Anyhow, if you happen to unearth the exact reason, please let us know.